# cmus playing status in format_title

Tags: cmus

is it somehow possible to display the playingstatus of cmus like

`head -n1 <<< $(cmus-remote -Q)`

in the format_title?

I am using sway and was hoping that i could use that window name to inhibit swayidle (not using pulseaudio so i couldnt find any solutions)

p.s. sorry if i missed something out at this post, its my first one^^

What i have tried:
reading man pages,
using search engine without any result

---

EDIT

Post fix: add answer as answer, not in post so i can mark it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i must have done something wrong the first time,... but the following actually works:

:set format_title=$(head -n1 <<< $(cmus-remote -Q) | awk '{print $2}') %a - %l - %t (%y)

So it still would be nicer to have a command like %a ;)

however its not solving my sway problem as that just changes the window title, not the app_id^^